# Chaining requests in Retrofit and RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, chaining, flatmap

I have ArrayList of strings. For each string, I want to call API with Retrofit2. And response of each API gives some data that I want to use and from there I want to call another API. Finally it will return string whether is success or not. I am able to achieve this but I want to all of the APIs should be called one after the other Like synchronous.

Here is my code looks like.

```
for (int i = 0; i < domainList.size(); i++) {
        feedData3(domainList.get(i));
    }

private void feedData3(String domain) {
        Domain domain1 = new Domain();
        streamFetch(domain)
                .concatMap((Function<Contact, ObservableSource<?>>) contact -> {

                    domain1.setDomainData(contact.getDATA());
                    domain1.setDomain(domain);

                    return streamFetchData(domain1.getDomain(), domain1.getDomainData());
                })
                .subscribe(new Observer<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                        disposable = d;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Object o) {
                        Log.e(TAG, domain + ",Success");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, domain + ",failure = " + e.getLocalizedMessage());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
    }


public Observable<Contact> streamFetch(String domain) {
        //GET API CALL
    }

public Observable<String> streamFetchData(String domainName, String domainData) {
        //POST API CALL
    }
```

Comment: when you request URL from domainList it return same response or not? and you using Rx1 or Rx2?

Comment: I am using rxjava2 and request is String and response is Observable<Contact>, it has some data. I want to use that data and send that again (POST).